# How to add permission of AzureDatabrick in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-databricks

I'm doing this tutorial.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/app-aad-token#use-an-azure-ad-access-token-to-access-the-databricks-rest-api

I followed the instruction and try to find AzureDatabricks in the Request API permissions page. But no results were found.

[image]

I'm sure that I'm an admin. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue, please follow the steps below.

1.Install the [Azure AD powershell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0#installing-the-azure-ad-module) in local.

```
Install-Module AzureAD
```

2.Then use `Connect-AzureAD` to login your admin account and run the command below.

**Note**: Don't modify the GUID `2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d`.

```
New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId "2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d"
```

[image]

3.Refresh the portal and navigate to the `API permissions` of your client app and add the permission, the `AzureDatabricks` will appear.

[image]